# ProgressDialog freezes when trying to run a service with an asynctask

Tags: android, service, android-asynctask

I have this code inside my asynctask:

```
@Override
protected void onPreExecute() {
    waitDialog = new ProgressDialog(context);           
    waitDialog.setTitle(R.string.wait_title);           
    waitDialog.setMessage(context.getString(R.string.wait_body));
    waitDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    waitDialog.show();
}

@Override
protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... unused) {
    Intent serviceIntent = new Intent(context, PublisherService.class);
    saveSettings(false);
    startService(serviceIntent);
    return serviceIsRunning();
}
```

The dialog shows but while my service is starting (and it takes a few seconds) the progressdialog is frozen. If i use a simple `SystemClock.sleep()` inside my `doInBackground()` call it works fine.

Can someone tell me why is this happening and how to solve the issue?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should not start any services from threads or asynctasks. Service could start its own thread and perform all work there. Or it's possible to bind to the service in onPreExecute() and call its methods from doInBackground. Read Local Service Sample here http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Service.html

Comment: Could you elaborate on why one should not start a service from an AsyncTask? Interested to understand why.

Answer (score 0):

If you use `SystemClock.sleep()` where? You mean instead of creating a service? Well first of all services and any other activity is created on the UI thread. So starting your service in an asynctask does nothing.

Comment: Yes, instead of creating a service. Creating a service freezes the UI but sleep() doesn't. How should I do it then?